Ensuring TLS Compatibility for Salesforce App Exchange Integrations
We're in the process of launching a free app for the Salesforce App Exchange. We've submitted our solution for security review, but unfortunately, it hasn't passed. Salesforce cited the need to upgrade TLS configurations from the external service and disable TLS versions below 1.2. They're requesting that we update all URLs in the package to use TLS versions greater than or equal to 1.2.
My understanding is that these changes need to be made by the third-party sites we're integrating with. We can't adjust Salesforce's configuration to exclusively use TLS >= 1.2 for callouts.
Do you have any suggestions on how to proceed from here?
Thanks!

If the external service does not support TLS 1.2 or greater, you won't be able to connect to it: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_other_changes.htm&release=220&type=5
